# Fragment is not recreated after popBackStack()

Tags: android

I have an Activity with a Layout named "container" where Fragments are inflated in using FragmentTransactions

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
transaction.replace(R.id.container, SomeFragment.newInstance());
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

One Fragment inflates another fragment with two more Fragments in a TabLayout. This is done with a TabLayout and a ViewPager. Everything works well until I pop it from the backstack.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

When I do this, the tabs are recreated and all the lifecycle methods are called. However, they have no content. They layouts seem not to be inflated.

I have a method called initUI(View v) which is called in

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabs, container, false);
    initUI(rootView);
    return rootView;
}
```

It does the setup for the TabLayout.

```
private void initUI(View rootView) {
    pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerCollected);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Again, this method is called but doesn't seem to do anything when popping the backstack.

What am I doing wrong here? Why is the Fragment not recreated properly even though the onCreateView and initUI are being called?

EDIT: In my TabsFragment, each Fragment has a RecyclerView. When clicking one of the Items, another Fragment opens up, displaying detailed information to the user.

Here the user can navigate back. When doing this, the TabsFragment is visible again but this time without any content. It seems like the inner fragments have not being inflated this time around.

Comment: What do you want exactly

Comment: Get an explanation of what I'm doing wrong and have the Fragment recreated properly. Sorry if that wasn't clear enough. I'll edit my question and make this more clear ...

Comment: Its not clear enough

Comment: That's why I answered you and edited my post. If you still don't understand my problem it's your turn to be more specific :)

Comment: You have an activity with a fragment that fragment has a viewpager within which you have two fragments right now i am not getting why are you doing popbackstack which fragment you want to remove exactly

Comment: I see the confusion. Sorry for that. I added the explanation at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 0):

First Add to back stack like this...

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
transaction.replace(R.id.container, SomeFragment.newInstance());
transaction.addToBackStack("YOUR_TAG");
transaction.commit();
```

After than try to popstackback()

Comment: Thank you but I'm already doing this. (sorry I removed the method addToBackStack(null) before posting this by mistake.